# Native way to accelerate (GPU) algorithms in Qt

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, parallel-processing, gpu

I have a functioning image processing program for a 3D scanner that is built on a multi-threaded Qt program written in Visual Studio utilizing a proprietary image processing library.  As the project has progressed the software has gotten more and more computationally heavy.  I have completed a number of software and hardware optimizations to increase its performance and have concluded that I really need to outsource several **repetitive algorithmic operations** (not graphics related) to the GPU.

I have experimented with using CUDA libraries only to realize that they do not integrate with Qt cleanly or at least at my level of understanding.  It appears that at some point in the past OpenCL was supported by Qt but does not appear to be the current direction of Qt development.

I have read a considerable volume of material on the subject and am curious what the **CURRENT** options (native to Qt or easily integrated) are for this sort of thing?

Comment: OpenCL is probably your best bet. You'll want a C++14 compiler. What compiler are you using? Qt shouldn't impact your usage at all. See: https://www.khronos.org/opencl/

Comment: I am currently using Visual studio 2015

Comment: You could try posting some of the integration errors you ran into with OpenCL in another post. Also see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2017

Comment: I did not have any integration errors with OpenCL.  I was merely reading old articles about QT wrappers of OpenCL.  The issue I had with CUDA was related to calling kernels from code that is inside a QT object (worker threads).  All of the work-arounds I read about look pretty ugly.

Comment: Why Qt? Qt is a GUI framework and not necessarily helping with all possible tasks. Consider PCL http://pointclouds.org/ and try to find pcl::gpu namespace in the code. http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/namespacepcl_1_1gpu.html

Comment: I am not stuck on Qt only options - "native to Qt or easily integrated"

Comment: We have Qt and bunch of PCL and few others depending on the project. Not all things even doable with Qt.